# GTMSessionUploader +load take too much time

Tags: google-signin

iOS GoogleSignInDependencies.framework involve the GTMSessionUploadFetcher, but the [GTMSessionUploadFetcher load] in launch phase take too much time, in my case is 95ms(see the pic below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWE2K.png)).
So, I wish Google Sign Team can remove the +load method or optimize the method, Thanks in advance.